# How to create a pop up form to allow user to input details to be saved in a table row

Tags: jquery, html

How can I make it possible for a user to click an add button, to which a pop up form would then be shown to allow a user to enter details and a comment. After entering these details, they could then save the changes which will be added to a table that is visible on the page in a row with columns that have headings the same as the details entered. I am a complete amateur developer so don't know where to start. Any help would be a appreciated.

Comment: Follow this link, I think it suits what you are expecting.http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form

Comment: This is perfect, thanks a lot

Comment: Cool! then you can mark my comment as useful

Comment: Is there any way to edit the code in this link to change to details I wish. The source is confusing within a lot of code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made a simple example for you to take a look at. It should be simple enough for you to change in any way you need:

[**JSFIDDLE EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/jzjjmztp/)

```
// Make the form a modal dialog and create a button
$('#emailModal').dialog({
    modal: true,
    autoOpen: false,
    title: "Enter your information",
    buttons: {
        "Send": function() {

            if ($('#emailPost2').submit())
            {
                $(".appendEmail").append("<tr><td>" + $(".email").val() + "</td></tr>");
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }

        }
    }
});
```